# Geopandas throws driver error when reading shp file

Tags: python, driver, gis, geopandas

Geopandas is throwing a driver error when reading a SHP file.

```
DriverError: '*PATH*/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.shp does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

All I am doing is this:

```
import geopandas
geopandas.read_file("*PATH*/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.shp")
```

The directory this pulls from includes all the other needed files downloaded from here:

https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html

and the actual files are here:
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.zip

Just to confirm that the file is not corrupt or anything I opened it up in QGis and it pulled up perfectly.

Comment: GeoPandas imports that file correctly on my system. You are sure that the file path that you specified is correct?

Comment: yes, this is the correct location. I was able to copy-paste it into windows explorer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else needs similar info: I, too, had a legit shapefile URL, [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) read_file threw an error: `DriverError not recognized as a supported file format`.

What worked for me is the following:

```py
import fiona

with fiona.open('/path/to/my_shapefile.shp') as shp:
   ax = geo.plot()
   #...rest of code
```